# Should/how can I use threading to improve a python script?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, i2c

I have a fairly simple python script that continuously polls internet sources for new data. When new data is found it writes it out to one of several i2c 4 character alphanumeric displays.

The problem is that the code to continuously scroll information on the displays requires a continuous loop. It would be much simpler to just call a function to write to the display then go back to polling for new data. Currently I have to incorporate the screen writing into the main data gathering loop.

Here is how I write to the display:

```
message = 'DATA: 1234567'
pos = 0
while True: 
    display.clear()
    display.print_str(message[pos:pos+4])
    display.write_display()
    pos += 1
    if pos > len(message)-4:
        pos = 0
    time.sleep(0.5) `
```

What are my options? Should I be using threading or is there another way of having interruptible background loops?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an asynchronous/event-driven framework like Twisted which supports timers: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/10/running-functions-periodically-using-twisteds-loopingcall/ - this keeps everything in one thread, and it gives you asynchronous APIs for doing HTTP GET, so you don't hang the display if one of your data sources is slow to respond.

Comment: Still means that I have to keep the display loop with the main, correct? Because I have multiple displays I would really like to separate the display logic from the data.

Comment: @genepool99: No, you would do *everything* in the main thread, but you can put the logic into function called by a Timer in Twisted.